# python: how does the operators % and [::] work?

Tags: python, python-2.7

i have this code in python:

```
name = "Eti & Iosi"
print "%s" % name[::-1]
```

the output is :

```
isoI & itE
```

can someone explain how this happens?

Comment: What precisely don't you understand? Have you read https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange (which covers both slicing and `%` string formatting)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator `%` is the [old-style string formatting operator](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#old-string-formatting). String formatting replaces all `%s` (there are other types as well) with the contents of the tuple (in this case, since you have only one `%s`, you can provide just one string) you give in the right member of the operator. Example:

```
>>> s = 'Hello %s!'
>>> print s % 'world'
'Hello world'

>>> s = 'I like %s and %s.'
>>> print s % ('red', 'blue')
'I like red and blue.'
```

`[start:end:step]` operator is list (or any object that supports indexing) [slicing operator](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html). `[::-1]` means `take the object items from start 0 to end -1 (i.e. all of them) every -1 step`, which causes your string to be reversed.

Your code reverses `name` and prints it using a simple kind of string formatting.